# Почему получаю пустую HashMap таблицу?

Tags: java, hashmap

Есть три типа рабочих - Manager, Worker, Trainee. Trainee, Worker наследуются от Employee, Manager от Worker.
Надо общитать сколько заработал каждый тип сотрудников - Manager, Worker, Trainee.

payroll - метод, который вычисляет заработок каждого рабочего из листа employees и возвращает список пэйролов, в котором каждый элемент содержит 2 поля - ссылку на сотрудника и BigDecimal сумму заработка (он список возвращает - проверил).
Компиляция проходит без ошибок, но на выходе пустая мапа.

```
public static HashMap <String, BigDecimal> everyKindEmployeeEarn (List<Employee> employees){
        HashMap <String, BigDecimal> mapa = new HashMap<>();
        payroll(employees).stream().

                map((i)->mapa.containsKey(i.getEmployee().getClass().getSimpleName())?

                mapa.put(i.getEmployee().getClass().getSimpleName(),
                         (mapa.get(i.getEmployee().getClass().getSimpleName())).add(i.getSalaryPlusBonus())):

        mapa.put(i.getEmployee().getClass().getSimpleName(), i.getSalaryPlusBonus()));

            return mapa;
    }
```

Comment: Зачем получаете название класса? Ведь могут быть разные Employee и они будут отображаться 1 раз

Comment: потому, что задание - посчитать заработок каждого типа рабочих

Comment: поправил описание, было немного сумбурно написано...

Comment: Зачем здесь вообще стрим? Стрим не должен изменять внешнее состояние.

Comment: просто я учу сейчас стримы, поэтому пытаюсь решить задачу через стрим.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что косяк скорее в сего, что я что-то не допонимаю в работе хэшмапы. На мой взгляд, вроде как все правильно написано. Но возвращается пустая мапа в конце.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось map не работает с внешними переменными.
Я ее использовал как неприхотливый итератор, но он так не работает.
Когда переделал код под forEach - все заработало.

```
employees.stream().filter(i->i instanceof Manager).
                forEach((i)-> {Integer temp = mapa.containsKey(i.getManager())? 
                        mapa.put(i.getManager(), mapa.get(i.getManager())+1):
                        mapa.put(i.getManager(), 1);}
           );
```